# Вывод данных массива

Tags: php

Массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => tel
            [title] => Телефон
            [value] => +7 999 999 99 99
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
            [title] => Ф.И.О.
            [value] => Иванов. И. И. 
        )

)
```

Как вывести номер телефона и Иванов И.И. из такого массива?

Comment: $array[1]['value']

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 => array
        (
            "type"  => "tel",
            "title" => "Телефон",
            "value" => "+7 999 999 99 99",
        ),
    1 => array
        (
            "type"  => "text",
            "title" => "Ф.И.О.",
            "value" => "Иванов И.И.",
        )

);

echo $array[0]['value'].PHP_EOL;  // номер телефона
echo $array[1]['value'];          // значение "Иванов И.И."
?>
```